# DBUnit/Spring transaction not rolling back when using OracleDataSource

Tags: spring, oracle11g, dbunit

I'm trying to use DBUnit to insert spatial data into an Oracle database and then roll it back.  In order to insert the spatial data, I must use Oracle10DataTypeFactory which pulls in the other DBUnit Oracle extensions for spatial data types.  Internally, they will do a cast to an OraclePreparedStatement.  In order to get an OraclePreparedStatement, I use an OracleDataSource.  So when I use the following Spring configuration:

```
<bean id="testDataSource" class="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource" destroy-method="close">
  <property name="URL" value="${database.url}"/>
  <property name="user" value="${user}"/>
  <property name="password" value="${password}"/>
  <property name="implicitCachingEnabled" value="false" />
  <property name="explicitCachingEnabled" value="false" />
  <property name="connectionCachingEnabled" value="false" />
</bean>
```

The inserts never roll back.  I know it is associated with the OracleDataSource from the following testing.  Insert a row into a table that does not require spatial data.  Use the following configuration:

```
<bean id="testDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
  <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>
  <property name="url" value="${database.url}"/>
  <property name="username" value="${user}/>
  <property name="password" value="${password}"/>
</bean>
```

Everything works fine and the insert is rolled back at test completion.  Perform the same exact test with the OracleDataSource as shown previous, forget it, nothing is rolled back.  I've looked at autocommit being set to true, but unfortunately Oracle doesn't provide a method for setting on the OracelDataSource, at least not one I could find.  So in my test setup I explicitly set it to false with the following:

```
connection = DataSourceUtils.getConnection(dataSource);
connection.setAutoCommit(false);
```

But even that seems to be ignored.  Has anybody run into a similar situation?

Answer (score 0):

Spring Role Back only works correct, if a transaction is started.

So make sure that your test uses the Spring Runner (for example by annotating the test with `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)` )  and the test annotated by `@Transactional`.